Deeplinks in Flutter when app is killed opens different instance on Android
I am working on a Flutter project that I am now configuring it to work with deeplinks. I managed to get deeplinks working correctly on iOS but on Android I am half way there. I can deeplink to any screen in the app without any issues if the app is open or in the background. However, If the app is killed and I try to deeplink to any screen, the app behaves in a very weird state. First it opens the app in a logged out state (even though I am logged in) and the app becomes unresposive, and can't make any network requests.
I tried searching online to find a solution but nothing fixes the issue so far. Here's some solutions that I came across but didn't help:

Changing launchMode in AndroidManifest.xml to singleTask:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.hoarsecords.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
    <queries>            
        <package android:name="com.instagram.android" />
        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
        <package android:name="com.facebook.orca" />
        <package android:name="org.telegram.messenger" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.twitter.android" />
    
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" /> 
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.orca.provider.PlatformProvider" />
    </queries>
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
             <!-- Deep links -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="hoarsecords.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- App links -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="hoarsecords.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/provider_name"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
        <provider 
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" 
            android:authorities="@string/facebook_authorities"
            android:exported="true" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" 
            android:value="@string/facebook_client_token" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_notification" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data 
            android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" 
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <service
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"        
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>



Overriding onNewIntent() method in MainActivity.kt:

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "app.channel.shared.data"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == intent.action && intent.data != null) {
            val data: Uri? = intent.data

            // Revised intent flags
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

            // Process the deep link and send it to Flutter
            if (data != null) {
                handleDeepLink(data)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleDeepLink(data: Uri) {
        flutterEngine?.let {
            MethodChannel(it.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).invokeMethod("deeplink", data.toString())
        } ?: run {
            // Handle the case where the FlutterEngine is not initialized
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately none of the above solutions worked with me. If you have an idea on how to fix this issue, Please let me know.

You have explained your question well but haven't give context.
How are you implementing deeplinking? What procedure are you following.
When i first implemented deep linking in my flutter app i noticed that when the app was opening the desired screen, it was using context.go under the hood which was clearing out my auth state i was setting in the splash screen, so this might be the issue you are also encountering.
